# How can I achieve a fixed background image with scolling content?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a fixed background image in my webpage, but the content should be scrollable.That is, I want a margin without it's bottom part. 
Here's an example [website](http://www.seymourduncan.com).
We can see that the content is scrolling but the background isn't.
Please help me do this.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the body css style rules on your sample page, you'll see that the magic happens here:

```
   background: #d2a278 url("//cdo.seymourduncan.com/images/background.jpg") no-repeat fixed center top;
```

where the no-scrolling part is because of the `fixed` value.

Answer (score 0):

Use css background property

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/nj5bmwc7/